# Amending commit that's been pushed to remote already

Tags: git

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make a change locally and commit it.  A new `SHA1` hash is assigned
   to the commit.
2. Push to the remote.  At this time, the local and remote are fully in
   sync and the `HEAD` SHA1 is the same in both places.
3. Now make a new change that functionally belongs in the same change
   as 1. above and `git commit --amend` it rather than make it its own
   commit.  This changes the local SHA1.

At this point, `git status` reports that that the local and the remote are both ahead of each other by one commit because it can't tell that the latest local commit built on top of the one that's HEAD on the remote.  For delta purposes, the HEADs on the local and remote are two distinct commits (as opposed to knowing that the local was built on top of what is on the remote) and the common ancestor is `HEAD~1`. This causes a great deal of hassle as it (AFAIK) requires merging.

Is there a way to make git keep track of different commits on the same change (which I think should be easy to record to know the history when you do `git commit --amend`) so that it is possible to push just the incremental change to the remote without needing to merge first?

Answer (score 2):

if you mess with the local commit history (which is exactly what `--amend` does), your local and remote history will diverge and be incompatible. The only sensible way to fix this is `git push --force`.

It's generally considered to be good practice to avoid changing commits, especially after pushing them. If you want to have a proper tree of differences that you can incrementally push, you'll have to use branches and commit in these, pushing them individually, and merging them only when you need a merged version. Amending a commit effectively deletes the old and inserts a new one, so this is *not* something traceable; it's very un-git-like.

Comment: I figured it by now.  However, I am disappointed that git does not keep track of commits on the same change and know what commits a change is comprised of.

Comment: That's exactly what an individual commit is for -- tracking changes. If you explicitely modify the atomic elements of git's history, you can't expect to track that. Basically, you're abusing git.

Comment: Implementing the feature of which you are thinking would mean that a commit would actually have smaller pieces, e.g. a sub-commit for an amend.  Think about merging and rebasing and you will see the headache this would cause.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for `git commit --amend`:

> You need to be careful with this technique because amending changes the SHA-1 of the commit. It’s like a very small rebase – don’t amend your last commit if you’ve already pushed it.

The makers of Git are warning us to avoid amending commits once they have been pushed, so we would be wise to follow suit.

As the previous answer already mentioned, if you insist on amending your commit, then you are compelled to use `git push --force` to update the remote.  But if you do so, you run the risk of causing problems for anyone who has already pulled the remote.

As an alternative to amending a commit which has been pushed, you can simply make a new separate commit for the change.  It may not be as sexy as doing an `amend`, but it will keep things much clearer.